# Protractor Test Cases by sending key to md-auto-complete in Angular material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, angular-material

I want to send a key to the md-autocomplete but I am not able to send key into text field , Find code below

HTML:

```
 <md-autocomplete md-selected-item="selectedItem" md-search-text="searchText" md-items="item in getMatches(searchText)" md-item-text="item.display">
      <span id="xyz" md-highlight-text="searchText">{{item.display}}</span>
    </md-autocomplete>
```

Protractor code :

```
  it('checking my test case', function() {
    browser.get('http://localhost:8080/#/home');

    var inputSearchTextBox = element(by.id("xyz"));
    inputSearchTextBox.sendKeys('Boston , us , 02120');
  });
```

I am getting below error :

```
Test checking my test case
   Message:
     NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.id("xyz")
   Stacktrace:
     NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.id("xyz")
```

Angular Material Link :

[ms-AutoComplete Link](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdAutocomplete)

Is there any way I can send key to md-autocomplete tag text field

Comment: On the [md-autocomplete demo page](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete), I can successfully send keys to the autocomplete input: `element(by.css("md-autocomplete input#input-15")).sendKeys("California");`..

Comment: What is input#input-15 ?

Comment: It is the underlying input that you can find inside the `md-autocomplete`.

Comment: NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector("md-autocomplete input#input-15") --> I got this error

Comment: Interesting. Could you show the complete test you are executing and the protractor config? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can add an id to your md-input-container with **md-input-id** attribute in your html.
For instance :

```
 <md-autocomplete md-input-id="xyz" md-selected-item="selectedItem" md-search-text="searchText" md-items="item in getMatches(searchText)" md-item-text="item.display">
      <span md-highlight-text="searchText">{{item.display}}</span>
 </md-autocomplete>
```

After that, you can access and use it with:

```
var myElt = element(by.css("md-autocomplete input#xyz"));
myElt.clear();
myElt.sendKeys("blabla");
```